# How to introduce the necessary info in the pivot table?

Tags: php, laravel

To update the conference registration form is necessary to introduce in the pivot table "registration_type_question" after user click in "update" button:

- the "registration_type_id" of the selected checkboxes
- the "question_id" of each question
- if its a required question or not for each registration type based on selected checkboxes (selected registration types)

Layout example: https://ibb.co/kftnPc

**pivot table "registration_type_questions" columns:** registration_type_id, question_id, required (boolean)

The pivot table "registration_type_questions" don't have a model. I have the update method in the QuestionController to update the registration form based on the selected checkboxes but I'm not understanding how to insert in the pivot table the necessary info, do you know how?

**Relevant relationships for the question:**

```
 1 to many between RegistrationType and RegistrationTypeQuestions
 1 to may between Question and RegistrationTypeQuestions 
 1 to many between Conference and Question
```

**Full Form**

```
<form method="post" class="clearfix" action="{{route('questions.update', ['conf_id' => $conf->id])}}">

  {{csrf_field()}}

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <table class="table table-striped table-responsive-sm">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Info</th>
                <th scope="col">Include in registration type</th>
                <th scope="col">Mandatory Field</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>
                  <i class='fa fa-check font-size-lg text-primary ml-4'></i>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <i class='fa fa-check font-size-lg text-primary ml-4'></i>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Surname</td>
                <td>
                  <i class='fa fa-check font-size-lg text-primary ml-4'></i>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <i class='fa fa-check font-size-lg text-primary ml-4'></i>
                </td>
              </tr>

              @foreach($question as $q)
              <tr>
                <td>{{$q->question}}</td>
                <td>
                  @foreach($registration_type as $rtype)
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input name="rypes[]" autocomplete="off" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{ $rtype->id }}" id="{{$rtype->id}}">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                      {{$rtype->name}}
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  @endforeach
                </td>
                <td>
                  @foreach($registration_type as $rtype)
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input name="mandatories[]" autocomplete="off" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{ $rtype->id }}" id="{{$rtype->id}}">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                      for the registration type "{{$rtype->name}}"
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  @endforeach
                </td>
              </tr>
              @endforeach

            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right mt-3" value="Update"/>
</form>
```

**QuestionController update method:**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){

        $values = $request->get('rtypes');
        $mandatories = $request->get('mandatories');

         $this->validate($request, [

        ]);

}
```

**Question Model:**

```
class Question extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'question', 'type', 'conference_id',
    ];

    public function registration_type(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\RegistrationType', 'registration_type_questions');
    }
}
```

This dd($mandatories); or dd($values); returns always, independently of the selected checobxes, this:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "1"
  1 => "2"
]
```

The "dd($id);" returns the conference id:

```
"1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the model, you can save it and aditional data using sync

Assuming `$id` is the question id

```
$question = Question::find($id);

$relationSync = array_merge(
  array_fill_keys($mandatories,["required" => true]),
  array_fill_keys($values,["required" => false])
);

$question->registration_type()->sync($relationSync);
```

Source docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: This might not be 100% correct since you don't give enough information, for example if `Question` has the relationship set and its name with `RegistrationTypeQuestions`.

Comment: Thanks but like that it appears "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::RegistrationTypeQuestions()".

Comment: that is what i said in the comment, what do you have in your `Question` model?

Comment: Thanks, I update the question with the Question model.

Comment: Thanks but its not working properly, in "$question = Question::find($id);"
this "$id" it seems that is the conference id, not the question id, and there is only two registration types (one has id "1" another id "2") but its appearing some records in the "registration_type_questions" pivot table where the column "registration_type_id" is 0, 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: and then how are you trying to pass the questions to the controller?. you should then in your checkboxes, send them as multidimensional array and loop through the questions and then the rtypes

Comment: In the view, I can access the question id because I have the foreach "@foreach($question as $q)...". But to send all the question_id of each question to the controller I don't know how to do that because there is no form inputs with question_id to send when the update button is clicked.

Comment: Check this as an example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26762851/using-multidimensional-array-input-names-with-laravel-4-2-form-facade-throws-err in your checkboxes, define their name as : `name="question[{{$question->id}}][rtypes]"`

Comment: Thanks, it appears "Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. "

Comment: its `$q->id`, the variable you're looping and not the array

Comment: Thanks, the foreach that you say that is necessary is like this "foreach($question as $q){
            foreach($values as $v){

            }
        }"?

Comment: when reading the data in the controller? yes, loop through questions and then get the mandatory  / non mandatory fields and do the method `sync` i have in the answer

Comment: But the mandatories checkbox "<input name="mandatories[]" " is not inside "@foreach($question as $q)".

Comment: it is in your question

Comment: Thanks, I have the example a little different in the question to reduce the  question size, but I already change and now it is inside the "foreach($question)".

Comment: I have "foreach($question as $q){
            foreach($values as $v){
                $mandatories = $request->get('mandatories');
                $relationSync = array_merge(
                    array_fill_keys($mandatories,["required" => true]),
                    array_fill_keys($values,["required" => false]));
                $question->registration_type()->sync($relationSync);

            }
        }" but it appears "array_fill_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given".

Comment: what does `dd($q);` after the first foreach output?

Comment: It shows "array:2 [▼
  "rtypes" => "1"
  "mandatories" => "1"
]"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166902/discussion-between-sergio-reis-and-johnz).